# Vaadin UI Testing getPage(),getLocation() with JUnit4

Tags: java, vaadin, junit4

I am trying to test one of the classes which has a Vaadin UI parameters,

at the test execution level i have a null pointer exception

```
String basePath = getBasePath();
```

This part can not be reached by the test case because of the getBasePath() method is not reachable due to NullPointerException.

```
protected String getBasePath(){
    String basePath = "";

    String host = UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getHost();
    int port = UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getPort();
    String path_app = UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getPath();
    String http_s = UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getScheme();
```

So in this part of this code,I tested that

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage()
```

Has a result, It is not null and test can reach to it. But the getLocation() has a null pointer exception.

```
@Before
public void init() throws URISyntaxException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {

    TetUI tetUI = new TetUI();
    UI.setCurrent(tetUI);
    UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("Something");
      }
```

I set the Location like that or could be a URI as well, But it is still null.

I tried to have some other sources about the topic on the internet and nothing came out yet.

Maybe i do it in a completely wrong way , Is this approach is correct? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting values through Vaadins static methods doesnt work very well.

You have two options:

1. Mock static method call with PowerMock.
2. Wrap calling UI methods with facade and mock it with Mockito.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but even the Mock or PowerMock is not working in this situation, i tried both.